# Magento 2: set default data for an ui component field from DataProvider

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, default-values, data-provider

I want to set a default value for an uiComponent field (shipping_id in this case) from the DataProvider (not from the form's XML, but from PHP). This is because the default value is dynamic (i am creating a new record based on a shipping id).

In my DataProvider:

```
    public function getData()
    {

        foreach ($this->collection->getItems() as $item) {
            $this->_loadedData[$item->getId()]['general'] = $item->getData();
        }

        if (empty($this->_loadedData)) {
            //set default values

            /** @var ShipmentInterface $shipment */
            $shipment = $this->persistor->get('shipment');
            $this->_loadedData['general']['shipment_id'] = $shipment->getEntityId();
        }

        return $this->_loadedData;
    }
```

and in my form's XML i am having a fieldset:

```
    <fieldset name="general">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="shipment_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipment ID</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">hidden</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        ...
    </fieldset>
```

Anyway, the code above from the DataProvider is working partially, it loads existing data, but when adding, the hidden field has no value.
Any idea how to reference a field from a fieldset when adding/editing data?

What should be the structure of *$this->_loadedData* when adding/editing data?

Comment: I don't really understand your requirement but if you want to get value from another field you can use `imports` in the XML, you will get dynamic value if the field you want to get is observable https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_linking_concept.html

Comment: Hi Jimmy, i want to set an initial value for a field (ui-component) from PHP. I am blocked at this moment as i don't understand what should be the structure of the _loadedData (the variable that is sent from my DataProvider to the form)

Comment: I don't quite see the "default value" use case. The reason is when opening a grid page, the value will be populated from database, the value is in the database.

Comment: So if you want to make a place holder, you can use JS to do it. I'm not sure if XML/PHP can do the job

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value like this:

`$this->_loadedData['']['general']['shipment_id'] = $shipment->getEntityId();`

`$this->_loadedData` is indexed by the entity's id. A new entity doesn't have yet an id, so whatever is set in `$this->_loadedData['']` it will be loaded for new entities.